# Paypal Rest API on webshop provided to third party companies

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**Background**

We are developing a webshop that we sell to other companies.
The companies hosts the webshops and sell their products on their own servers.
The webshop uses the Paypal Rest API for the customers to make payments.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

To activate Paypal as a payments method the companies provide their Paypal details in the webshop admin area.

**How we do it now**

Right now the companies need to create a Paypal Developer account, and then create a new App in developer.paypal.com to get their own Client ID and Client Secret Code.

They then provide their Client ID and Client Secret Code in the webshop admin area.

**Question**

Is this the correct way to do it?
We think it feels a bit strange to tell our customers (the companies) to create "Developer Accounts" in Paypal, when they are not actually developers, just webshop owners selling their products.

I found this information about setting a parameter called "payee", which means you can set the receiver of the payments, see: https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/ and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-payee

Is it possible to use the "payee" as a solution instead, like this?:
We as developers of the webshop have a Paypal developer account, and provide our Client ID and Client Secret Code, which are then used in all our customers webshops? Then the companies would only need to provide their Paypal Account Email in the webshop admin area, which is then used as the "payee" parameter.

Is this a good and ok solution? Or is the same App, Client ID and Client Secret Code not allowed to be used for multiple companies and their webshops? How can we solve this then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved after communication with PayPal support.
This is some information from the communication that answers my questions:

*"Do not use then the payee field as you will be able to deal with all the transactions created, that you don't want as you are an external "actor" in the payment process."*

*"About creating a developer account and App it does not mean that they are developers. The developer portal is a tool that allow to manage the Apps and deal with Sandbox test accounts. It is the only way to create an App."*

So the conclusion is that we are doing it the correct way today, which is like this:

*"Right now the companies need to create a Paypal Developer account, and then create a new App in developer.paypal.com to get their own Client ID and Client Secret Code.
They then provide their Client ID and Client Secret Code in the webshop admin area."*